# variable use in dplyr and ggplot

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to sort out functional programming with dplyr/ggplot. In my first couple of weeks of R I mostly went by trial and error following snippets found on the web, but I'm trying to understand this better so it comes more natural.

I'm playing around with mtcars as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- mtcars
data$carb <- as.factor(data$carb)
```

My sample code w/o using variables looks like this:

```
data %>% filter(carb != 4) %>%
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp, color = carb)) +
ggtitle("Explicit/no variables")
```

and produces the expected:

[image]

I figured out how to call most everything via variables:

```
remove_col <- "carb"
remove_val <- 4

x_value <- "mpg"
y_value <- "hp"

data %>% filter( carb != remove_val ) %>%
ggplot() + geom_point(aes_string(x = x_value, y = y_value, color = remove_col )) +
ggtitle("Variables for `geom_point with aes_string` and for value to remove from `carb`")
```

This gives the same plot as above:
[image]

The thing I'm struggling with is how to address the column "carb" in `filter` via the variable `remove_col`. I have been going through tidyverse.org, but I am having a hard time sorting out `scoped verbs`, vars, across(), ...

So two questions:

1. How do I use the variable `remove_col` instead of the explicit `carb` in the `filter` statement?
2. Why do the two variables (`remove_col` and `remove_val`) behave differently in the `filter` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aes_string` has been deprecated and the preferred way now is to use `.data` pronoun which can also be used in `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

remove_col <- "carb"
remove_val <- 4

x_value <- "mpg"
y_value <- "hp"

data %>% 
  filter(.data[[remove_col]] != remove_val ) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = .data[[x_value]], y = .data[[y_value]],
                        color = .data[[remove_col]])) +
  ggtitle("Variables for `geom_point with aes` and for value to remove from `carb`")
```

---

You can also use `sym` with `!!` :

```
data %>% 
  filter(!!sym(remove_col) != remove_val ) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = !!sym(x_value), y = !!sym(y_value), color = !!sym(remove_col))) +
  ggtitle("Variables for `geom_point with aes` and for value to remove from `carb`")
```

Comment: Oh that's awesome. Nice that both calls are consistent with this. So `.data[[]]` really means: replace this part with the character string stored inside a variable? The one thing that's not clear to me though is the difference between using variables on the two sides of the argument in filter? Why does `remove_val` not equally need to be called with .data[[]]?

Comment: And two more questions for the second solution. I thought that !! is already 'unquoting' a variable, but when I tried it didn't work. Clearly I needed the symb() in addition. Why is that, and is there a reason to prefer `.data[[]]` over `!!sym()`? Do they differ in any way?

Comment: `.data` or `sym` is to be used only when we have variable for a column name, it is not applicable for values (`remove_val`). Values can be used as it is. I am not aware about any difference between `sym` and `.data` though. You can read more about it here https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: In addition to the URL posted by @RonakShah, the definitive treatment of non-standard evaluation and how Hadley Wickham created standardized the meta programming grammar into what is called tidy evaluation can be found in [Advanced R - second Edition](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html), chapters 17 - 22.