# using variable with .data[[]] in mutate in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I thought with my [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479529/variable-use-in-dplyr-and-ggplot) I had sorted out all issues in using variables in the tidyverse. But I just ran into a problem using the mutate function I do not understand. Below is a toy-example of piping a dplyr statement into ggplot.

I added an explicit mutate step `mutate(mpg = mpg * 10) %>%` which works just fine.

Also adding in the column by name with `.data[[]]` on the RHS of the statement works fine using `mutate(mpg = .data[[x_value]] * 10) %>%`.

However, when I use a variable on the LHS of the equation with `.data[[]]` or `!!sym()` as in `mutate(.data[[x_value]] = mpg * 10) %>%` I get:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"data %>% filter( .data[[remove_col]] != {{ remove_val }} ) %>%
        mutate(.data[[x_value]] ="
```

The obvious question: Why is this not working?
And the obvious follow-up: How can I use a variable to designate a column to mutate?

---

For reference, the working examples:

```r
#// library
library(tidyverse)
data <- mtcars
data$carb <- as.factor(data$carb)

remove_col <- "carb"
remove_val <- 4

x_value <- "mpg"
y_value <- "drat"

#// explicit mutate condition

data %>% filter( .data[[remove_col]] != {{ remove_val }} ) %>%
    mutate(mpg = mpg * 10) %>% 
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = .data[[x_value]], y = .data[[y_value]], color = .data[[remove_col]] )) +
ggtitle("Variables for `geom_point` and `filter`")
```

[image]

```r
#// add variable into mutate assigment

data %>% filter( .data[[remove_col]] != {{ remove_val }} ) %>%
    mutate(mpg = .data[[x_value]] * 10) %>% 
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = .data[[x_value]], y = .data[[y_value]], color = .data[[remove_col]] )) +
ggtitle("Variables for `geom_point` and `filter`")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things are handled differently depending on whether you have a variable on LHS or RHS. If you have a variable on LHS use `!!variable_name := ....` where `variable_name` should be a string value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


data <- mtcars
data$carb <- as.factor(data$carb)

remove_col <- "carb"
remove_val <- 4

x_value <- "mpg"
y_value <- "drat"

data %>% 
  filter( .data[[remove_col]] != {{ remove_val }} ) %>%
  mutate(!!x_value := .data[[x_value]] * 10) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = .data[[x_value]], 
                            y = .data[[y_value]], 
                        color = .data[[remove_col]] )) +
  ggtitle("Variables for `geom_point` and `filter`")
```

Comment: Argh!! I remember seeing this syntax before, but didn't really get. I guess it's just one more thing to remember. And I guess in the in the tidy-select functions where I used .data[[x]] in the past it was always in a conditional statement and not in assigning a value to a variable.